# Upload image and Attach in PHPMail at the same time

Tags: php, email, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image and at the same time attach it in the PHPMail.

Here's the code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        $fname = $_POST['Name'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $max_size = '5120';
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $file_ext = array("image/png","image/jpeg");

        if (in_array($type,$file_ext)) {
            if (!empty($file) && !empty($fname) && !empty($email) && isset($file) &&$_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
                {
                    $location = 'image_upload';
                    echo    $dir = $location.'/'.$file.'/';
                    if (is_dir($dir) == false) {
                        mkdir("$dir", 0777,true);
                        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$dir.$file);
                                    // Create directory if it does not exist
                    }
                    echo '<p style="color: green;">Your image was uploaded successfully.</p><a href="index.php">Back</a>';

                    require_once('mail/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');

                    $email = new PHPMailer();

                    $email->From      = 'rodgieseromines891@gmail.com';
                    $email->FromName  = 'Nostlgc';
                    $email->Subject   = 'File Upload';
                    $email->Body      = 'Test Upload';
                    $email->AddAddress( 'mjoedelacruz@gmail.com' );

                    $email->AddAttachment($tmp_name, $dir . $file);

                    return $email->Send();
                } else {
                     echo '<p style="color: red;">All fields are required!</p>';
                }
            } else {
                 echo '<p style="color: red;">Please put a valid file format!</p>';
            }
    }
```

What happens here is it only uploads the file and forgets to attach it as mail. After i execute this code the second time it sends the file as an attachment.

Comment: I think the $dir.$file should be before the tmp_name. I would actually get rid of the tmp name all together and do it as one parameter.

Comment: Did you make sure `$tmp_name,$dir.$file` points to the full path of the file?

Comment: @VitorRigoni - yes, it is the full path to the file. I'm saving the file in a directory of its own with it's name as the folder name.

Comment: @MartinE. - if i do that, it's folder destination would be empty and the file won't be in its path.

Comment: @MichaelJoeDelaCruz
The first parameter is the path... The second is the name.

$email->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

Comment: @MartinE. ive just tried what you've suggested. still works the same. thanks for helping.

Comment: Works the same as it doesn't work?

Comment: @MartinE. - yes, it doesn't work.

Comment: Check the assignment of $size. Looks suspicious. Is it a typo?

Comment: @OguzOzgul - yes, it's a typo. i have already removed it. the problem here is it doesn't execute the   move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$dir.$file) and  $email->AddAttachment($tmp_name, $dir . $file); at the same time. what happens is it uploads but does not attach the email. but after you have uploaded the file, it will now send an email if you upload the same exact  file.

Comment: It seems, you are calling move_uploaded_file only if the directory does not exist. Or am I wrong?